# Finding Cumulative Distribution Function from an interval

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, cumulative-distribution-functions

The time for a taxi to arrive is approximately uniformly distributed on the interval (0,6). Find the cumulative distribution function.

My attempt was:
F(x) = 
0 such that x < 0,
x such that 0<= x <= 6,
and 6 such that x > 6.

Comment: You need to scale everything down, so that it ramps up from $0$ to $1$ over [0,6] rather than from $0$ to $6$. Otherwise you have it right.

Comment: $F(x)$ denotes a probability hence can only take values in $[0,1]$.

Comment: In general the cdf is $F(x)=\frac{x-a}{b-a}$, if $X$ is uniformly distributed on $(a,b)$.

Comment: @callculus or $F(x)=\dfrac{\min(\max(x-a,0),b)}{b-a}$ for $x \in \mathbb R$

Comment: @Henry Sure I´ve omitted the cases $X<a$ and $X>b$. Your expression is nice and tricky, but a little to difficult for the OP-I think.